# How can I log my data to S3 with Rubicon-ml?

Tags: machine-learning, logging

How can I log my rubicon-ml data to s3 for further collaboration? For example, if I have created an experiment with rubicon-ml and have logged that information locally, I also want to share that with others.

Answer (score 0):

The [rubicon-ml docs](https://capitalone.github.io/rubicon-ml/faqs.html) cover how to log to s3 directly with rubicon-ml.

> Data can be logged either directly to S3 or to the local filesystem
> first, and then synced with S3.
>
> **Direct S3 Logging**
>
> Configure the Rubicon object to log to S3: from rubicon_ml import
> Rubicon
>
> ```
> rubicon = Rubicon(
>     persistence="filesystem",
>     root_dir="s3://my-bucket/path/to/rubicon-root",
> )
> ```
>
> If you’re logging from your local machine, be sure to [configure your AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html).
>
> If you’re logging from an EC2, ensure that the IAM role that your EC2
> instance is using has at least `s3:GetObject`, `s3:PutObject`, and
> `s3:DeleteObject` actions allowed for your S3 bucket:
>
> ```
> {
>     "Sid": "AllowS3Objects",
>     "Effect": "Allow",
>     "Action": [
>         "s3:GetObject",
>         "s3:PutObject",
>         "s3:DeleteObject"
>     ],
>     "Resource": [
>         "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET_NAME]",
>         "arn:aws:s3:::[BUCKET_NAME]/*"
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> We recommend using the asynchronous [client](https://capitalone.github.io/rubicon-ml/library_reference.html#library-reference-async) when logging to S3 directly.
>
> **Syncing the Local Filesystem with S3**
>
> Local logging can easily be synced with an S3 bucket using
> Rubicon.sync().
>
> ```
> local_rubicon = Rubicon(persistence="filesystem", root_dir="/rubicon-root")
> local_project = local_rubicon.get_project("Sync Example")
>
> local_rubicon.sync(
>     project_name=local_project.name,
>     s3_root_dir="s3://my-bucket/path/to/rubicon-root",
> ) This would result in the local “Sync Demo” project being copied to the specified S3 bucket. Under-the-hood, it uses the AWS CLI `sync`
> ```
>
> method. So, you’d need to have the AWS CLI installed and ensure your
> credentials are set.